# maven 3 Failed to read artifact descriptor for

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I upgrade to netbeans 7 which uses embeded maven 3. I have a project with lot of modules and modules containing other modules. My other submodules that don't depend on internal projects work fine with the same configuration. In this case, spring-hibernate depends on domain which is one of the submodules and fails.

my main project has something like this

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<groupId>${masterproject.groupId}</groupId>
<version>${masterproject.version}</version>
```

my submodule has the following def

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <groupId>${masterproject.groupId}</groupId>
    <version>${masterproject.version}</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>spring-hibernate</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependency>
        <groupId>${masterproject.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am using the following ${masterproject.groupId}, ${masterproject.version} because I don't want to put static value in all the submodules as each one contains a parent. Not sure if this is the cause of the problem.

All of this works fine with maven 2. But with maven 3 I get the following error msg

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.merc:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find ${masterproject.groupId}:MavenMasterProject:pom:${masterproject.version} in http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.release has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Nope, I updated the pom.xml to use static value like snapshot-1.0. But would like to use properties instead

Answer (score 8):

I had this in eclipse and did this which fixed it(even though my command line build worked)

1. delete the directory in .m2/repostiory/....
2. rerun update dependencies in my IDE

mvn command line worked while my IDE didn't, once I ran it in my IDE both worked..very weird.

As another option,
restarting eclipse seemed to help as well

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me. Frustrating that my IDE (netbeans) and CL maven step on each others toes... I am in the habit of doing most mvn and svn stuff from a terminal, but when I cleaned and built w/ dependencies, everything started working again....

Comment: yeah, I preferred ivy and copy jars into output/libs so don't have to use m2eclipse plugin which seems to have had problems for the last 6 years I have used it on and off.

Comment: Funny you mention m2eclipse. Its actually the reason I switched from eclipse to netbeans. I really like maven (or rather, I really like the idea of maven. Sometimes it really frustrates me), and netbeans has killer maven support.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is you are specifying the values for `masterproject.groupId` and `masterproject.version` in `profiles.xml`. If so, it is [no longer supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html) in maven3.

Answer (score 0):

That message, especially that `Failure to find` part, means that you lack the description of the appropriate property in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
    <masterproject.version>the.appropriate.version</masterproject.version>
</properties>
```

And be careful: such error could evoke many dependent errors!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, maven does not like having a non-constant (i.e. a property) parent version.

Try changing your parent element to:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <groupId>${masterproject.groupId}</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Obviously, it doesn't have to be `1.0-SNAPSHOT` it just has to be some static version.

Hope this helps.